# Can't find file error in Middleman site on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, middleman

I've setup a Middleman site as per this guide (http://www.randomerrata.com/articles/2013/middleman-on-heroku/) for deploying to Heroku. When I load the site in a browser though an error appears:

```
Rack app error: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 404.html>
```

Everything seems to be setup correctly, I've provided a screenshot of my source directory structure and config.ru. What could the problem be?

[image: heroku-papertrail]

[image: middleman-config-ru]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like the build is never being built which results in no index.html file loading, and subsequently the 404 failing to load.

Looking at `bundle exec middleman build` it appears to be wrapped in talking marks `''` rather than the grave accent ``` `` ``` - not sure on the technical difference but it appears like changing line #8 to include ` builds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify absolute path:

```
page_404_file = File.expand_path('../build/404/index.html', __FILE__)
File.open(page_404_file, File::RDONLY)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I do this I'm getting this error `#<Errno::ENOTDIR: Not a directory - /app/config.ru/build/404/index.html>`. I switched it to './build/404/index.html` too but that provides this error `#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/build/404/index.html>`. Is there a way to see what's inside a Heroku slug? (i.e. to confirm where on earth the file is?).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm… I'm the author of that blog post and it looks like something odd is happening here. For some reason Rack is trying to open `404.html` despite the fact that line 27 is plainly trying to open `build/404/index.html`.

I hate asking this, but everything's saved and committed to Heroku, right?

You can also try to open up a bash console on Heroku so see what's going on there (just execute `heroku run bash` in your terminal prompt).

---

Edit: oh, *Alexander R Lunnon* below noticed that the `middleman build` line is wrapped in single quotes ( ' ) not backticks ( ` ) as it should be. That might be the main issue.